# Mobile: How to detect if user is still scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, touch, dom-events

I'd like to do an action when the user stops scrolling. The problem is that `onscroll` events are only fired as long as the user keeps moving his finger. If he keeps his finger still, no event will be fired. So a timeout won't work.

I tried hooking into the touch events, but as soon as the browser realizes that the user wants to scroll, it will fire `touchcancel` and no more touch events are fired.

Is there a way to detect when the user lifts his finger up from scrolling?

Comment: A possible workaround is to use a library like [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4), which captures touch events to simulate scrolling. It also happens to have a "snap" feature, which is what I was trying to implement in the first place.